# Tokenize each row in a dataframe - for loop not working

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, textblob

I am trying to tokenize a sentence in a pandas dataframe but I am having some trouble

I know this code works to covert just one row

```
TextBlob(df['H'][0]).words
```

But when I tried to apply it in a for loop I got an error

```
for i, row in df.H():
ifor_val = TextBlob(df['H'][i]).words
df.at[i,'ifor'] = H
```

Error message:
TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable

Edit:

```
data = {'H':['the quick brown fox jumps over the road', 'the weather is nice 
today'], 'marks':[99, 98]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

desired

```
H                                  marks
['the','quick','brown', 'fox'....]   99
['the','weather','is', 'nice'....]   98
```

SOLUTION:

df['H']=df['H'].apply(word_tokenize)
df['H'].head()

Comment: Please fix your indentation and post your error message. It would help us solve your problem.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] with 5 or so rows of data with expected output. Thanks.

Comment: @d_kennetz TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable

Answer (score 0):

You may be wanting to apply a function to every row in a dataframe.  In this case you can use lambda to apply a function once per row over the entire dataframe.

Assuming H is the column you are targeting, and each row is the exact text you want to send to TextBlob, the following would add a column called 'output' which would be the result of the TextBlob fuction

```
df['output'] = df['H'].apply(lambda x: TextBlob(x))
```

Comment: I tried that and it tokenizes the word to be just each letter vs a word

Comment: try TextBlob([x])) in the lambda function

Answer (score 0):

this gave me what you wanted  :

```
data = {'H':['the quick brown fox jumps over the road', 'the weather is nice today'], 'marks':[99, 98]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 

print(df)


df2 = df.drop("H",axis=1).copy()


df2.insert(loc=0, column='H', value=[[] for x in range(df.shape[0])])

for index, row in df2.iterrows():
    vals = df.loc[index,"H"].split()

    for word in vals : 
        df2.loc[index,"H"].append(word) 

print(df2)
```

Comment: i updated my answer please try it and see if this is what you wanted

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate over index - value(strings in this case) pairs of a column, you will need the iteritems() method of the column:

```py
for i,  s in df.H.iteritems():
    pass #  Do stuff with your values
```

Better add a new column, instead of overwriting the old.